# How to remove "see" from info links / cross-references?

Tags: documentation, info

I'm generating Django documentation to more easily reference it in Emacs. The obvious approach[^] results in cross-references having "see" prepended to them. E.g., the online documentation for [Model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/) says:

> This document describes the details of the **Model** API. It builds on the material presented in the [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/) and [database query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/) guides, so you’ll probably want to read and understand those documents before reading this one.

whereas opening the texinfo in `Info` results in:

> This document describes the details of the ‘Model’ API. It builds on the
>   material presented in the **see** [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/) and **see** [database query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/).
>   guides, so you’ll probably want to read and understand those documents
>   before reading this one.

How can I get rid of this "see"?

---

[^]: The obvious approach being:

```
git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
cd django && git checkout stable/1.11.x
cd docs && make texinfo
cd _build/texinfo && sudo make install-info
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the variable `Info-hide-note-references`. Specifically, setting it to `'hide` results in the behavior I want. The [Sphinx FAQ](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/faq.html#displaying-links) goes into more detail about this, and suggests the following advice to automatically enable this on sphinx-generated files (Fixed since the regex they suggest wasn't working)

```el
(defvar-local Info-hide-note-references t)

(defun fov-auto-hide-info-note-references (&rest _args)
  "Advice to automatically hide 'see' in info files generated by sphinx."
  ;; Adapted from http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/faq.html#displaying-links
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (when (re-search-forward
             "^ *Generated by \\(Sphinx\\|Docutils\\)"
             (save-excursion (search-forward "\x1f" nil t)) t)
        (setq Info-hide-note-references 'hide)))))

(advice-add 'info-insert-file-contents :after #'fov-auto-hide-info-note-references)
```

Comment: I wonder if Sphinx could be convinced to write a file-local variable to set this up automatically?

Comment: That's a phenomenal idea! You could probably do it as part of the build step in shell even if Sphinx doesn't comply