# Texinfo produces "see" for @ref commands in Info-mode

Tags: info, manual, texinfo

I'm trying to produce a manual in `Info` format and I'm getting  a little confused about `@ref` and the `*note/see` markers.

I thought that for **HTML** output, `@ref` would behave like `@xref` and produce the `'see'` marker, as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Info-Format-FAQ.html):

> Why do I have ‘see’ appearing in front of all of my links?
>
> By default, Emacs Info mode either changes the marker ‘*note’ for cross-references to ‘see’, or hides it completely. Command-line info does the same if hide-note-references is set. Unfortunately, there is no way to do this reliably, as both the @pxref and @ref commands in Texinfo output this marker in the Info output, and the ‘see’ text is only appropriate for @pxref.
>
> Yes, but how do I get a plain link, with no extra markup?
>
> You can’t. Info is a plain text format that is displayed mostly as-is in the viewers, and without the ‘*note’ text there would be nothing to mark text as a link. Additionally, in printed output there is no such thing as a plain link, as the page number of the target would have to be printed somewhere.

But I find that this also happens when I'm browsing a manual in `Info-mode` as well, albeit inconsistently.

As an example, if I look at the `.texi` source for the AucTeX manual, I find a few `@ref` commands:

```
If the last process you started was
on the region, the commands described in @ref{Debugging} and
@ref{Control} will work on that process, otherwise they will work on the
process associated with the current document.
```

This is translated into

```
   If the last process you started was on the region, the commands
described in *note Debugging:: and *note Control:: will work on that
process, otherwise they will work on the process associated with the
current document.
```

and when viewed in Emacs, looks like this:

[image: AucTeX manual vied in Info-mode]

So the first `@ref` command has the `'see'` hidden, while the second displays it.

In general, I find that the `AucTeX` manual manages to keep the appearances of `'see'` to a minimum – is there some strategy that allows one to do this? E.g. no more than one `@ref` per line/node? Or is this just something we have to live with (until maybe someone comes up with a `*note-no-see` marker)?

And yes, I've also read about `Info-hide-note-references` (which has been set to `t` in my Emacs), including in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39276/how-to-remove-see-from-info-links-cross-references), which suggests some kind of file-local variable setting as a solution – though I'm not sure how to implement it.